# Why is the Logarithm of a negative number undefined?

Tags: logarithms, definition

The Definition of a Logarithm is:

If $$x^y=a$$
Then $$\log_xa=y$$

Given this definition, since $$e^{i\pi}=-1$$

Then shouldn't $\ln(-1)=i\pi$? What is wrong with it?

Comment: Why is it not $-i\pi$?

Comment: What about $e^{-\pi i} = -1, e^{5\pi i} = -1$, $e^{2\pi i} = 1, e^{24\pi i} = 1$? If you go complex, the logarithm of all numbers becomes ambiguous.

Comment: There's nothing "wrong with it," but many of the rules about working with logarithms become more complicated when you allow arguments outside the positive reals.  For instance, $2\ln(-1) \neq \ln((-1)^2)=\ln(1)$, no matter what single value you choose for $\ln(-1)$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not [undefined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm).

In fact, [Ahlfors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lars_Ahlfors) treatment of complex analysis begins with exponentiation and logarithms.  As the other comments point out, once you accept complex values, there is an inherent problem as uniqueness fails: If $t=e^z$, then also $t=e^{z+2n\pi i}$ for any integer $n$, so one has to choose which of these infinitely many values $z+2n\pi i$ will be distinguished as "the" logarithm of $t$.

We can, however, choose the values of logarithm in a way that the resulting function is continuous (in fact, analytic) at the cost of not having it be defined everywhere on $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$: We need to remove at least a line from the *punctured* plane line so that the domain of logarithm does not contain a loop about the origin; continuity imposes this restriction; think of $e^{i\theta}$ for $0\le\theta\le2\pi$, we get a discontinuity once we have completed traveling along the loop. We refer to this choice of domain as a choice of *branch*. [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/280640/462) further discusses why this is needed.

When one chooses as domain $\mathbb C\setminus\{x+0i\mid x\le 0\}$ with $\log (a+ib)$ being the number $\ln\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+i\arctan(b/a)$, with the arctangent $\theta$ chosen so $-\pi<\theta<\pi$, we call this the *Principal branch*, usually denoted $\mathrm{Log}(z)$.