# Logarithm contradiction

Tags: logarithms

What is wrong with this reasoning?

$\ln(4)=\ln((-2)^2)=2\ln(-2)$

We can obvisouly work out $\ln(4)$, but we can't with $\ln(-2)$. The reason I am asking is because I have a situation in another problem where I arrived to something similiar to $2\ln(-2)$ and I don't know if I should just write $\ln(4)$.

Comment: I think you could be interested in the complex logarithm function (it is a multifunction though) which should be defined for this. I think you'd have $ln(-2)=In|-2|+i\pi = In(2)+i\pi$ I think so that $2In(-2)=2In(2)+2\pi i$

Comment: The ratio of the natural log of negative one to the square root of negative one happens to be $\pi$...not that that helps any.  ;)

Comment: The rule $\ln(x^a)=a \ln x$ is only valid for $x>0$, so you can't apply it with $x=-2$. In that other problem where you arrived at $\ln(-2)$, you must have done something strange, but you'll have to tell us more about that before we can help you.

Comment: The property of logs which you are using, namely $\log a^n=n\log a$ only holds for $a>0$, as you have discovered.

Comment: For complex number z in polar form:
$z = r·e^{iθ}$
The complex logarithm:
 $\log z = \ln r + iθ$
Is defined for negative z.
so we have $\ln z=\ln r+i\theta \to z=e^{r}+e^{i\theta} $
but $e^{i\theta} = \cos(\theta ) + i \sin( \theta)$
so if $z\in R$ then $e^{i\theta}=\pm1$ so for negative z (r is positive because it is Radius) we must take $e^{i\theta}=-1$ but $0<e^{r}$ so we haven't $\ln (-2)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a reason why mathematicians used to think that logarithms of negative numbers are equal to logarithms of positive numbers (it used to be somewhere on the Wikipedia, I'll try to find it).  However, logarithms of negative numbers can indeed be defined, but they are not so simple.

$$4=e^{2\ln(-2)}=e^{2\ln(2)}$$

This equality is true if we define $\ln(-2)$, and such is explained [in this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/511174/why-is-the-logarithm-of-a-negative-number-undefined).  However, the inverse is not true:

$$\ln(-2)\ne\ln(2)$$

This is because there just so happens to be the case that

$$e^{2\pi i}=1$$

And

$$2\ln(-2)=2\ln(2)+2k\pi i$$

for some whole number $k$.

Thus, we end up with

$$e^{2\ln(-2)}=e^{2\ln(2)+2k\pi i}=e^{2\ln(2)}e^{2k\pi i}=e^{2\ln(2)}$$

Comment: this guy's high school must be insane

Comment: @Euler_Salter Which guy?  ;-)

Comment: This girl? To be honest I don't know the neutral appellative in English, so I just sticked to the past male appellative, but anyway good job

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you did something wrong with your calculation and here is the proof 
assume $\exists$ number $x<0$ so that $\ln(x)=y$ with $y\in\mathbb{R}$
 then

$$\ln(x)=y$$

$$x=e^y $$ 
this leads us that $e^y$ is negative which is obviously a contradiction to its definition as it is always postive .

Comment: You seem to miss the fact that it is $x=(e^y)^2$, so the end result is still positive.

Comment: What I meant is that you can't reach  ln(-2)  with any mathematical arguments . There must has been a mistake that you did while calculating.

Comment: You mean me in my answer?  No, I didn't, you can reach $\ln(-2)$, but that requires analytic stuff.

Comment: why don't you show us the question if you are so sure ;)

Comment: What do you mean?  Since it seems you aren't very familiar with these things, please see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function#Complex_plane)

Comment: I am familiar but you said that the reason you are asking is because you had this result as an answer to a problem you had . I am asking you about the problem

Comment: What do you mean?  I didn't ask the question, I am one of those who answered it lol.

Comment: ohhh well i am really embarrassed now  sorry for bothering you

Comment: XD No problems.